# How to parse soap response from web service to get value of node using java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am getting soap response from web service. I  need to parse to get the value inside the node. Please provide some code to parse the soap response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.org/Response" userid="100">
  <name date="23-10-2013">Sample</name>
 <name date="02-09-2013">Hello</name>
  </ns3:Response>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you give some more information reg. the circumstances? Why dont you just use the WSDL für the service?

Comment: Hi.. I need the values of "name","date","userid" tags. How can I get using WSDL? can you please explain

Comment: If you have a wsdl for the service you could just use `wsimport` to generate client stubs for consuming the service. You would not need to do any XML parsing at all.